# Как открыть word-файл при нажатии на картинку. HTML

Tags: html

Есть картинка на странице. Как при нажатии на нее открыть определённый word-файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что MS Office это не часть W3C.

В решении 3 ссылки.

Первая это стандартный диалог открытия файла.

Вторая это открытие word с помощью ActiveX. Работает только в IE

Третья это использование протокола Microsoft. Он предполагает наличие на компьютере установленного Офиса выше 2010.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWord(strFilePath) {
        var yourSite = "file:///D:/site/";
        openWordDocPath(yourSite + strFilePath);
    }
    function openWordDocPath(strLocation) {
        var objWord;
        objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
        objWord.Visible = true;
        objWord.Documents.Open(strLocation);
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="test.docs"> <img src="1.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="#" onclick="openWord('test.docx')"> <img src="1.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|https://ec.europa.eu/idabc/servlets/Docc966.doc" > <img src="1.jpg" /> </a>

</body>
</html>
```